# defunct dbus-daemon zombie freezes ssh login for 30 seconds

Tags: ssh, login, dbus

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (Precise Pangolin) and noticed a 30 second delay whenever i log into my server via ssh or perform any kind of login via sudo on that machine.
I can provoke immediate execution by killing the defunct dbus-daemon showing up during the delay:

output of ps fax |grep dbus

```
19222 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
19752 ?        Z      0:00  \_ [dbus-daemon] <defunct>
```

taping into the dbus using dbus-monitor --system i'm getting:

```
signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=(null destination) serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.4"
   string ""
   string ":1.4"
```

each login.
Stopping the dbus service eliminates this problem but probably causes many other...
I'm not running xorg on the machine but the packages are present for X11 forwarding capabilities.
I've ruled out the common motd script delay and ssh "UseDNS no" fixes one finds when looking up login delay issues.
Many thanks in advance for any help with this, it's been driving me crazy ;-)